Is it possible to write AWS Lambda function with streamed response in C#
I want to make a lambda function that returns a 12-13mb files. According the docs, for regular functions response payload limit is 6mb - for streamed - 20mb.
I found a documentation with streamed lambda example:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-response-streaming.html
But was not able to find such example for C#. Is it possible using C#?

The linked document says, "Lambda supports response streaming on Node.js managed runtimes. For other languages, you can use a custom runtime with a custom Runtime API integration to stream responses or use the Lambda Web Adapter." Have you tried either of those suggestions?
